# How to specify dummy data for testing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I am working on the UI for an MVC project that uses Backbone.js. The work on controllers etc. is not over yet, but I want to test the UI changes that I have made. I have defined the following model:

```
app.models.Test = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: '/users/getTestValues',
        fetch: function (data) {
            return $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                url: this.url(),
                **data: data**               
            });
        }
    });
```

The view is using this model to render a template (containing a table of 2 cols) on the UI.

```
{{#each data}}          
<tr>                                        
<td>{{this.T1}}</td>
<td>{{this.T2}}</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

The below controller is just used as a placeholder:

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonpResult  getTestValues(int? entityId, int? id)
        {
            return JsonpResult(WebResult.Success());
        }
```

How should I hardcode the "data" value for testing?
I tried adding this to the model, but it doesn't work:

```
dataFilter: function (response) {                    
                    return { data: [{ "T1": "test1", "T2": "test2"
                    }]
                    };
                }
```

Comment: in the response - data is "null"

Answer (score 1):

You could just hardcode the values in your controller or use a library like [Mockjax](https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax) to intercept AJAX requests and return data.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult getTestValues(int? entityId, int? id)
{
    return Json(new { "T1": "test1", "T2": "test2" });
}
```

Comment: How can I hardcode them on the controller? I tried doing this but it didn't work.